# ScreenCloud Update - Dependency Is Not Satisfiable

Tags: 12.10, software-installation, software-center

ScreenCloud offered an update yesterday, and as it didn't show up in the Update Manager (I have it set up to fetch both important and other updates), I decided to check the Ubuntu Software Center. The version there is the same one that was released last summer or so (1.1.0), so I went on and downloaded the latest version from their website. Trying to install that one I got an error saying that the dependency "libquazip0" is not satisfiable.

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 x64. I downloaded libquazip 0.6.2 (the latest version) but I don't know how to install it. I worked with tar.gz archives before, but I usually followed the developers' instructiond on where and how to install them. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I managed to fix this. For anyone else who might have this problem:

[Download QuaZip here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libs/libquazip0). Select your architecture type (32 or 64-bit), download from one of the mirrors, install. After that run ScreenCloud installation.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! You could mark it as answer to your question.

Comment: QuaZip didn't exist at that link any more, but I [found it here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/kubuntu-ppa_backports/precise/main/base/libquazip0).

Answer (score 0):

you can also install libquazip1

```
sudo apt-get install libquazip1
```